# Is it possible to create multiple tables in hbase?

Tags: hbase

I have visited so many links but couldn't find any solution on this that "Is it possible to create multiple tables in hbase?"if yes then how?

Comment: create 'table1','cf1' . create 'table2','cf1'. It creates two tables table1 and table2 in hbase. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: no,using HBaseAdmin instance is it possible?and how would we know that the two tables belong to the same region..!if creation of two tables is possible then how key ranges would be defined for each and then alloted to the region server?

Comment: @Tariq yess in one shot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to have multiple tables in same region.

This is not possible, because regions are part of a table and not viceversa (tables part of a region).
Each table is split into regions and each region is served by one region server.
When created, unless specified, each table has only one region.

The [Regions Architecture](https://hbase.apache.org/book/regions.arch.html) chapter in the HBase Book points out the architecture of a region.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it's not possible to create multiple tables in one go. **[HBaseAdmin](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html)** implementation currently doesn't support this.

As an alternate you could create a list of tables and loop through it, calling **HBaseAdmin.createTable(HTableDescriptor desc)** in every iteration.